# How to scan New network card or any other devices in linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I am trying to add a New Network card into Machine which has Linux installed.  But my problem is, I cannot reboot the Linux host to detect the new network card, is there any workaround for this? 
I know, linux supports adding new disk without reboot by scanning scsi bus. 
Any idea, How to scan New network card?

Kernel Version = 2.6.18-308.el5

Comment: Have you tried as root `echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan` after making sure all the hotplug modules or kernel config directives are enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If the card isn't detected and configured instantly when you hotplug it, then run `udevadm trigger` as root.

Comment: Not worked!!!! no messages in dmesg logs regarding the same

Comment: In that case, you can reboot.

Comment: I know reboot will solve my problem,  but somehow i would like to know to hotplug a device in linux.